# How to put repository onto another repository as branch so they have some shared commits?

Tags: git, migration, branch, git-merge, bazaar

I have bazaar repos, A and B. They have some shared commits, because B diverged from A some time ago. What I need to do, is to export them to git, so now I have two git repositories, but (it's difference between git and bzr), it's no way to perform merge between them.

```
bazaar-------------------A
            mergable
bazaar---------------------B
```

Basically, i need to put repo B on repo A as branch. Any ideas how to do that?

```
git---------.---------------A
            |__________B
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to initialize the Git repository:

```
git init
```

Then export the bzr repositories:

```
bzr fast-export --plain . | git fast-import
```

You'll need to do this for both of the repositories separately. The commits should (provided that the fast-export works as expected) result in a common history between them by shared SHA hashes; you can then pull from one repo into the second one under a different branch.

```
git fetch /other/git/repo && git checkout -b BranchB FETCH_HEAD
```